# remove empty checkbox from the cell in handsontable

Tags: angular, checkbox, handsontable

// I have an array of Object like below

```
data = [{name:{value:'A',active:true},{address:{value:'Pune',active:false},
        {name:{value:'',active:false},{address:{value:'Delhi',active:false}]
```

columns are like below,

```
columns: [ {
      data:"name.active",
      type:'checkbox',

      label:{
        position:'before',
        property:'name.value'
      }
      },
      {
      data:"address.active",
      type:'checkbox',

      label:{
          position:'before',
          property:'address.value'
      }
      },
]
```

How to avoid creating empty checkbox for the the empty names. I have tried by settings hot.setDataAtCell(1,0,'') but its not working. If I get the data using hot.getData()[row][col]
its returning null values. I want to clear the empty checkbox.

Comment: Issue solved by adding style dispaly:none for the checkbox